# How to run CSS keyframes if PHP condition is met?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have an opening animation that I only want to run if an user visits the website for the first time. I don't want the user to see the animation each time the user reloads the page, so I want the animation only to run if a cookie isn't set for the user.

Example psuedocode:

```
if (cookie(userAlreadyVisited) is set {
doAnimation
}
else
{
doNotAnimate
}
```

And the animation would be something like this:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Div animation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="main"><h1 id="headline-fade">Welcome!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

#main {
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    width: 750px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

#headline-fade {
    animation-name: fontFade;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: Roboto;
}

@keyframes example {
    0% {
        background-color: white;
        width: 2px;
        height: 2px;
    }
    50% {
        background-color: white;
        width: 2px;
        height: 500px;}
    100% {
        background-color: white;
        width: 750px;
        height: 500px;
    }
}

@keyframes fontFade {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        margin: auto;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
        margin: auto;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        margin: auto;
    }
}
```

To summarise, I only want the keyframes to run if the user is visiting for the first time or if the cookies have expired.
**I have tried jQuery.Keyframes** but I can't make it work.

Comment: Provide jquery code that you have tried

Comment: Let PHP check for the existance of the cookie and apply a class to the body or another element.  Use that class as a selector in your CSS for which to run the animation on.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/jjDjRW3F
it's ugly, but readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let PHP determine if the cookie exists and use that in a conditional statement to add a class to the element that may or may not be animated.

Then you can extend your CSS with that class and only apply the animated styles to elements that have this class.

As an example:

**In Your CSS:**

```
#main {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    width: 750px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
#main.animated {
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes example {
    0% {
        background-color: white;
        width: 2px;
        height: 2px;
    }
    50% {
        background-color: white;
        width: 2px;
        height: 500px;}
    100% {
        background-color: white;
        width: 750px;
        height: 500px;
    }
}
```

In your HTML:

```
<div id="main" <?php if (!isset($_COOKIE['userAlreadyVisited'])) { echo class='animated' }; ?>>
<h1 id="headline-fade">Welcome!</h1>
```

PS: Your closing `</h1>` tag is missing in your original code example.

Answer (score 0):

Only set the `animation` if it has a particular class in the CSS, and in the PHP (or in javascript) only give that element that class if the user already visited.

Answer (score 0):

Just Keep everything Same expect integrate php code with html like this i guess this would work Perfectly
Try this...

```
    <?php if (!isset($_COOKIE['userAlreadyVisited'])) { 
?>
<div id="main"><h1 id="headline-fade">Welcome!</div>
<?php
} ?>
```

Here isset will check whether the cookie is stored or not and then just a simple if condition if it gets true it will execute the statement which is in your case is welcome message and if it didn't get true it will skip the Welcome message